# If block statement it not executed when comparing data retrieved from MySql DB

Tags: java, mysql

am trying to update a student database by clicking the Button

```
JButton NewUpdate = new JButton("UPDATE");
    NewUpdate.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.BOLD, 14));
    NewUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String  regNo   =   RegNoCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String  subjectCode =   SubjectCombo.getSelectedItem().toString(); //gets value selected from subject code JCombobox
            double  score   =   Double.parseDouble(scoreTextField.getText().toString());
            String  testType    =   AssesmentCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();//gets value selected from assessment code JCombobox
            String  queryFromScoresTable    =   "SELECT CONCAT(student_id,subject_id) FROM scores;";
```

The switch statement below determines the option selected by the teacher. and retrieves information from the DB, by using the "queryFromScoresTable" above

```
            switch (testType) {
            case "Class Work":
                try {
                    conn3   =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/resultchecker_db","%username%","%password%");
                    ps3 =   conn3.prepareStatement(queryFromScoresTable);
                    rs5 =   ps3.executeQuery();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);
                }
                try {
                    rs5.next();
                    String  compareData =   rs5.getString(1);
```

the query retrieved from the DB is converted to a string with the variable name "compareData"

The "if" statement below is supposed to check if the student "regNo" and "testType" exists, if it does the block is executed by updating the information on the table

```
                    if((regNo + subjectCode).equals(compareData)){
                        String  queryUpdateStudRecord   =   "UPDATE scores SET class_work=? WHERE student_id=? and subject_id = ?;";
                        conn4   =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/resultchecker_db","%username%","%password%");
                        ps4 =   conn4.prepareStatement(queryUpdateStudRecord);
                        ps4.setDouble(1, score);
                        ps4.setString(2, regNo);
                        ps4.setString(3, subjectCode);
                        ps4.execute();
                        rs5.next();
```

Else this block is executed by inserting the student regNo and the score for selected testType into the DB.

```
                    }else{
                        String  queryInsertRecord   =   "INSERT INTO scores(student_id, subject_id, class_work) VALUES (?,?,?)";
                        conn4   =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/resultchecker_db","%username%","%password%");
                        ps4 =   conn4.prepareStatement(queryInsertRecord);
                        ps4.setString(1, regNo);
                        ps4.setString(2, subjectCode);
                        ps4.setDouble(3, score);
                        ps4.execute();
                        rs5.next();
                    }
```

The problem however is that only the "else" statement executes without evaluating the "if" statement, which means that if there already exists a regNo, it cannot be updated. Since it will return an existing primary key error.

Assistance is needed, thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why the `if` doesn't trigger, but you could just go with a single query:

```
INSERT ...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE student_id=VALUES(student_id), subject_id=VALUES(subject_id)
```

Then you don't need to care whether you should do an update or an insert - let the DB decide for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with equals() method. Please try to debug and see what you are getting in (regNo + subjectCode) and compareData.